# How to change the title of contacts page in coding in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, page-title

I have done a website in magento. In that website, I have contact page. I have inserted the keywords,description in the contact page But when I am giving the title, it is not showing in the website. Why is it like that ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please able to add screen shot it make clear you are talking about which title?

Comment: i have attached the screenshot..

Answer (score 1):

1. On your  `FTP/cPanel` server in the folder where the Magento files are stored, go to `\app\design\frontend\default\theme_number\layout\contacts.xml` or `app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme_number/layout/contacts.xml` in newer templates.
2. If you do not see the `contacts.xml` file in the theme folder, you should copy it from `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` to the theme folder.

Open it with any code editor and change the name of the page around line 38:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action  method="setTitle" translate="title"  module="contacts"><title><strong>Contact Us</strong></title></action>
</reference>
```

3. Save the changes, remove the cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Hi..I tried all these..I want to know from where the title Contact Us is coming...So edit there.

Comment: It will come from contacts.xml as i mentioned, you can change it in specific theme if you have.

Comment: I tried to change it in the theme...but it is not reflecting in the frontend...

Comment: Assume you are using same theme and there is no overrides for contacts  module by custom extension, Remove the cache and try again. it will definitely work.

Comment: No..I tried to comment all the title code in the xml files..but it is not reflecting in the front side..

Comment: Are you using windows are linux(Ubuntu)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48928/discussion-between-lena-and-krishna-ijjada-at-i95dev).

Answer (score 1):

add `contacts.xml` to your theme at

```
app/design/frontend/Your-Namespace/Your-Theme/layout/contacts.xml
```

change lable in below code

```
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Add your label here</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
```

Also you can add above code in `local.xml` of your theme.